# How to make SSH ignore some user logons?

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh

I put a openssh-server on my test-server, it works very well. But soon, I realized whatever name of account that I putted in - like `ssh XXX@192.168.1.1` - the server always answer my request and let me input password. Actually it won't allow root or other non-exist account to log in. But obviously that's not a safety phenomenon. And I test some little web site, it also answer my ssh request, although i tried input "root" and failed to log in.

So how to let openssh-server ignore some request except the account I specified. I tried ssh some big web site it clearly ignore my request and just left my waiting.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is impossible to accomplish. The connection is established before any `user` existing/non-existing check is performed. You can however limit networks that has access to your openssh-server.

Comment: @val0x00ff Sure, it will make the initial connection. But I don't see a problem (in theory) with getting ssh to reject paswords from some accounts. But I don't see the point of this. Perhaps the poster can describe his use case?

Comment: @FaheemMitha, maybe I'm misreading the question though but this is how I understand it. The OP wants the connection to be dropped if e.g  `ssh xxx@192.168.1.1` was issued. The `Allowusers` directive within `sshd_config` is meant to exclusively allow users that are in the list. This however won't be able to drop the connection abruptly.

Comment: @val0x00ff I think what the poster requires is not completely clear.

Answer (score 1):

In fact it is the contraty: it is **more** secure to first wait from the username and the password before replying authentication error, without giving details on which part is wrong.

If the server would reply with the information "No such username" immediately after having received the username it would make it less secure as it would be trivial to enumerate the list of existing user accounts, just by sheer brute force, without having to guess passwords (the space - aka possible values - of all usernames is far smaller than the one of all passwords, due to their syntax constraints).

Note also that `ssh` access is not only username+password, you can also login with username + private key for example (and a given username may have multiple keys it wishes to use, when a user has only one password).